# SQL Spatial Query

Tags: sql, postgresql, spatial-query

How do I get this to give me all the data from the Featurepoint table whilst also providing the data from the featuresite table (where it exists)

```
SELECT 
       P.Name, 
       C.short_name
FROM FEATUREPOINT P, 
     FEATURESITE C
WHERE ST_INTERSECTS(C.shape, P.position) = 'TRUE';
```

Comment: What do you exactly want? You want the same query but getting every field in both `FEATUREPOINT` and `FEATURESITE` tables?

Comment: I want all the names from featurepoint. Then I want the featuresite names when the names overlap. All displyed in the same table

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `left join`. All rows from `FEATUREPOINT` are returned, and `C.short_name` will either be `null` (not match) or the value from `FEATURESITE`

```
SELECT 
       P.Name, 
       C.short_name
FROM FEATUREPOINT P 
   LEFT JOIN FEATURESITE C 
     ON ST_INTERSECTS(C.shape, P.position) = 'TRUE';
```